# split numbers based on special characters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

I have a column as below:

```
numbers
---------
225/271-2001  
5565/2233-123
1392551-6,X117
```

The rule is: separate the number based on dash(-) and slash(/).The comma should be removed(if present).The 'X' is considered as an extention will remain as is. I need to separate this as shown below.
I understand, both the patterns are different. However, I can consider this separate while writing the query.
I would like to split these numbers as below:

```
number1     |      number2
---------------------------
2252001           2712001
5565123           2233123
1392551X117       1392556X117
```

I tried with below query:

```
SELECT 
    ID, number
    , STUFF(
        LEFT(number,CHARINDEX('-',number)-1),
        LEN(LEFT(number,CHARINDEX('-',number)))-LEN(RIGHT(number,CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(number))-1)),
        LEN(RIGHT(number,CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(number))-1)),
        RIGHT(number,CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(number))-1)
    ) 
    , SUBSTRING(number,CHARINDEX('/',number)+1,LEN(number)) AS [2ndnumber]
FROM [tablename] 
WHERE numbers LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

However, I'm not getting the result as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of SQL server?

Comment: SQL Server 2016 would help.

Comment: You have to explain the rules that you are trying to apply. From the first two rows it seems like / operates like OR and - looks like concatenation. The last row doesn't seem to follow these rules?

Answer (score 0):

You have different rules for numbers with `/` and `,`. So you have to divide your query. Here's one way:

```
declare @t table (numbers varchar(20))
insert into @t
values ('225/271-2001')
    , ('5565/2233-123'), ('1392551-6,X117')

select
    number1 = left(numbers, ci1 - 1) + right(numbers, len(numbers) - ci2)
    , number2 = substring(numbers, ci1 + 1, ci2 - ci1 - 1) + right(numbers, len(numbers) - ci2)
from
    @t
    cross apply (select ci1 = charindex('/', numbers), ci2 = charindex('-', numbers)) a
where
    charindex('/', numbers) > 0

union all

select
    left(numbers, ci1 - 1) + right(numbers, len(numbers) - ci2)
    , left(numbers, ci1 - 1 - (ci2 - ci1 - 1)) + substring(numbers, ci1 + 1, ci2 - ci1 - 1) + right(numbers, len(numbers) - ci2)
from
    @t
    cross apply (select ci1 = charindex('-', numbers), ci2 = charindex(',', numbers)) a
where
    charindex(',', numbers) > 0
```

Output

```
number1        number2
----------------------------
2252001        2712001
5565123        2233123
1392551X117    1392556X117
```

Comment: Thanks. Its very generic. And I'm getting error when applying on table. The error is : "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.".
As query in the question is working for the 1st two records. Could you please suggest, if considering the 3rd record in "With CTE" and write a logic (after getting 3rd records 
in where condition[where number LIKE '%X%' AND number LIKE '%,%'  AND number LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9]%']?

Comment: @AskMe, your query works only for first record and does not return your expected output. And query like `number LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9]%']` will be length depended, and may not work for all cases like your query in the question. Regarding the error check your data in the table. There might be some values not in the format that you have provided

Answer (score 0):

Try below, it may help.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(ID INT, number varchar(200))

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(1,'225/271-2001')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(2,'5565/2233-123')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(3,'1392551-6,X117')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(4,'13925515-65,X119')

SELECT ID,number
    ,CASE   -- When the pattern is '#/#-#'
            WHEN CHARINDEX('/',number) > 0 AND CHARINDEX('-',number) > CHARINDEX('/',number) 
                THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(number,1,CHARINDEX('/',number)-1) AS VARCHAR(50))
                    + CAST(SUBSTRING(number,CHARINDEX('-',number)+1,LEN(number)) AS VARCHAR(50))
            -- When the pattern is '#-#,#'
            WHEN CHARINDEX('-',number) > 0 AND CHARINDEX(',',number) > CHARINDEX('-',number) 
                THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(number,1,CHARINDEX('-',number)-1) AS VARCHAR(50))
                    + CAST(SUBSTRING(number,CHARINDEX(',',number)+1,LEN(number)) AS VARCHAR(50))
            ELSE number
        END [1st number]
    ,CASE   -- When the pattern is '#/#-#'
            WHEN CHARINDEX('/',number) > 0 AND CHARINDEX('-',number) > 0 
                THEN CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(number,CHARINDEX('/',number)+1,LEN(number)),'-','') AS VARCHAR(50))         
            -- When the pattern is '#-#,#'
            WHEN CHARINDEX('-',number) > 0 AND CHARINDEX(',',number) > CHARINDEX('-',number) 
                    THEN LEFT(CAST(SUBSTRING(number,1,CHARINDEX('-',number)-1) AS VARCHAR(50)),(CHARINDEX('-',number)-1)-LEN(RIGHT(LEFT(number,CHARINDEX(',',number)-1),CHARINDEX(',',number)-1-CHARINDEX('-',number))))
                        + CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(number,CHARINDEX('-',number)+1,LEN(number)),',','') AS VARCHAR(50))
            ELSE number
        END [2nd number]
FROM #temp
```

OUTPUT:

```
ID    number              1st number      2nd number     
----- ------------------- --------------- ---------------
1     225/271-2001        2252001         2712001
2     5565/2233-123       5565123         2233123
3     1392551-6,X117      1392551X117     1392556X117
4     13925515-65,X119    13925515X119    13925565X119
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should give the expected result. Simple query using xml format.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(ID INT, number varchar(200))

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(1,'225/271-2001')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(2,'5565/2233-123')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(3,'1392551-6,X117')

;WITH Split_Names (ID,xmlname)
AS
(
    SELECT ID, 
    xmlname= CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',number)=0      
                  THEN CONVERT(xml,'<Names><name>'  
                               + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(number,'-', '<?name><name>'),'/', '</name><name>'),'?','/') + '</name></Names>') 
                  WHEN CHARINDEX(',',number)>0  
                  THEN CONVERT(xml,'<Names><name>'  
                               + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                                 REPLACE(REPLACE(concat(LEFT(number,(CHARINDEX('-',number)-1)),CAST('/' as char(1)),LEFT(number,(CHARINDEX('-',number)-2)),SUBSTRING(number,CHARINDEX('-',number)+1,1),',',substring(number,CHARINDEX(',',number)+1,LEN(number))),'-','/'),',','-')
                                 ,'-', '<?name><name>'),'/', '</name><name>'),'?','/') + '</name></Names>') 
             END
    FROM #temp
)
select xmlname.value('/Names[1]/name[1]','varchar(100)')+ xmlname.value('/Names[1]/name[3]','varchar(100)') NUMBER1,
       xmlname.value('/Names[1]/name[2]','varchar(100)')+ xmlname.value('/Names[1]/name[3]','varchar(100)') NUMBER2
from Split_Names
drop table #temp
```